# Using ID card authentication library c header

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to C++ (long line since last programming) but I was asked to take a look at a programming issue and alter a ready made code. Basically what we try to do is to use Id card authentication library. The below code aims to feed PIN  and card reader name in order to authenticate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <DigiSign_Toolkit.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
SValue pin, reader, tst;
InitializeLibrary();
cout << "Test1" << endl; // debug
SValueString("1234", pin);
SValueString("Reader name X", reader);
cout << "Test2" << endl; // debug
BYTE tries;
BYTE auth = 2;

bool result = Authenticate(reader, auth, pin, tries);

SValueFree(pin);
SValueFree(reader);

ReleaseLibrary();

return 0;
```

In the code the function `SValueString(xxx, yyy);` which is used to put the authentication values to variables seems not to work (code not continuing but no errors) and if I comment the lines out the second `cout << Test2` gets printed to console normally.

The code is using these functions from C header file:

```
struct SValue
{
    DWORD len;
    BYTE *val;
};

//
BOOL DSAPI SValueString(const char *inValue, SValue &outValue);
```

I have been digging around, but seem not to find anything that could work in here. So, all the help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck asking the library vendor for support, at a guess `pin` needs to be initalised

Comment: `from C header file:` the part `SValue &outValue);` is invalid in C.

Comment: If the code doesn't continue there is an error. Run your program in a debugger?